# How to use Spark Dataset API to aggregate Key-List?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

With `Spark 2.x`, starting from such a `Dataset`:

```
|keyword    |url
|A1         |url1
|A1         |url2
|A1         |url3
|A1         |url4
|A2         |url1
|A2         |url2
|A2         |url3
```

How could I obtain:

```
|keyword    |url
|A1         |url1,url2,url3,url4
|A2         |url1,url2,url3
```

Comment: you can use `collect_list()`

Comment: Hi,thanks for quick response.  Able to share more detail sample ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GroupByKey and create lists of values pyspark sql dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945174/groupbykey-and-create-lists-of-values-pyspark-sql-dataframe)

Comment: @moto, yes, should be duplicate from the post. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = myDataset.groupBy("keyword").agg(collect_list("url"))
```

Using `agg()` with `GroupBy()` will let you do what you need under `agg()` you will get some methods like `collect_set()`, `sum()` etc.

Comment: Hi Akash, your quick response is pretty good which solved my problem which spent me a day...!! Thanks a lot !!

By the way, any way to format the output of collect_list ? like self define the delimiter ?

Comment: i think we are bounded by only the avaliable methods if you want to to do defining something then you need to apply `map() ` operation i.e. transformation

Answer (score 0):

In addition to accepted answer, if you wish to do the same thing in lambda way

```
        baseDS.rdd.filter { x => !x.getAs[String](0).contains("keyword") }.map { x =>
      (x.get(0), x.get(1))
    }.groupByKey().foreach(println(_))
```

**Note:** The *filter()* operation can be skipped with schema definition

**Result**

(A1,CompactBuffer(url1, url2, url3, url4))

(A2,CompactBuffer(url1, url2, url3))